# Rearrange 2-dimensional array dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays

how to dynamically convert this type of array:

```
[
    [a,b,c],
    [d,e,f],
]
```

into

```
[
    [a,d],
    [b,e],
    [c,f],
]
```

the length of the first array is not always the same size.

tried the following

```
for (var i = 0; i < multi.length; i++) { // 2
    for (var j = 0; j < multi[i].length; j++) { // 3
        multi2[j].push(multi[j][i])
    }
}
```

it does not work

Comment: Try a Google search for array **transposition** in JavaScript.

Comment: The outer loop should iterate `arr[0].length` times, while the inner loop iterates `arr.length` times.

Answer (score -1):

Two issues:

1. Initialize your multi2 subarray for i.
2. You have your i and j mixed up in the inner loop.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xa6bF/)

```
var multi = [
  ["a","b","c"],
  ["d","e","f"],
  ["g","h","i"],
]
var multi2 = [];

for (var i = 0; i < multi.length; i++) { // 3
  for (var j = 0; j < multi[i].length; j++) { // 3
    multi2[j] = multi2[j]||[]; // initialize subarray if necessary
    multi2[j].push(multi[i][j])
  }
}
```